# User Frontend Selection That Loads Images From Database With Django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, ajax

I have a drop down bar with a multi selection tool. A user picks from titles of graphs stored in a model for the graphs they want to display. How can I use those selections to display these graphs? I am using Ajax to send the data to the backend. From that data I created a new context_dict full of the model objects we want displayed. I want to either display in the same template or link to another template that can use this context dict. I do not know the best way to do this. Here is some of my code below.

Models:

```
from django.db import models

class ChartPrac(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    chart = models.ImageField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Views:

```
def querier(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        options_arr = request.POST.get('optionsArr')

        options = options_arr.split(':')
        options = options[1:]
        print(options)

        context_arr = []
        context_graphs = {}
        i = 0

        for elements in options:
            charts_to_display = ChartPrac.objects.get(title=elements)
            context_arr.append(charts_to_display)
            i += 1

        context_graphs['titles'] = context_arr

        return HttpResponse(options_arr)

    else:
        graph_titles = ChartPrac.objects.all()

        context_dict = {'titles': graph_titles}

        print(context_dict)
        print(type(context_dict['titles']))

        return render(request, 'graph_querier/base.html', context=context_dict)
```

Urls:

```
from django.urls import path
from graph_querier import views

app_name = 'graph_querier'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('querier/', views.querier, name='querier'),
    # path('graph/', views.graph, name='graph'),
]
```

Template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Marketing Querier</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://res.cloudinary.com/dxfq3iotg/raw/upload/v1569006288/BBBootstrap/choices.min.css?version=7.0.0">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dxfq3iotg/raw/upload/v1569006273/BBBootstrap/choices.min.js?version=7.0.0"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'graph_querier\querier.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
    
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background-color: rgba(0,96,155,255)";>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'main_dash:main_dash' %}">Main Dashboard</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Marketing Dashboard</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Sales Dashboard</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Input</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Input</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Input</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </nav>

  <div id="title">
      <h1 id="graph-querier-text">Graph Querier</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center mt-100" id='search'>
    <div class="col-md-6"> <select class="select-option" id="choices-multiple-remove-button" placeholder="Select up to 10 Graphs" multiple>
      {% for graphs in titles %}
        <option class="option-rend" value={{ graphs.title }}>{{ graphs.title }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
      </select> </div>
  </div>

  <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){

      var multipleCancelButton = new Choices('#choices-multiple-remove-button', {
      removeItemButton: true,
      maxItemCount:10,
      searchResultLimit:1000,
      renderChoiceLimit:1000
      });


      });
  </script>

  <script src="{% static '\graph_querier\javascript\base.js' %}"></script>

  <div id='render-graphs'>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick='rendGraphs();'>Render Graphs</button>
    {% csrf_token %}
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
function rendGraphs(){
    var select = document.getElementById('choices-multiple-remove-button');
    var csrf = $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();

    var optionsArr = [];

    for (var x = 0; x < select.length; x++){
        var temp = select.options[x].text;
        optionsArr.push(temp);
    }

    var stringOptions = ''
    for (var i= 0; i < optionsArr.length; i++){
        var stringOptions = stringOptions.concat(":" + String(optionsArr[i]));
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: '/query/querier/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'optionsArr': stringOptions,
               'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf
        }
      }).done(function(response){
          console.log(response)
      });
}
```

Comment: I figured this out. Create separate model with foreign key as user. Save ajax to new model. Call in to different template with different view. Filter by user. For loop through selections the user chose.